# How can I copy SqlDataReader values into an array

Tags: c#, t-sql

I am new to the programming world, I am trying to capture all the values ​​of the database through a `SqlDataReader` and execute well until some part, problem is when the database sends more than one row. Returning the second row changes all the data in the first row.

That's my code

```
public List<MethodServiceModel> QueryMethod(int idMethod)
{
        List<MethodServiceModel> list = new List<MethodServiceModel>();

        try
        {
            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                conn.Open();
                NpgsqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

                // Retrieve all rows
                var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("\"integrador\".\"GET_METODO_SERVICIO\"", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":id_metodo", idMethod);

                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    MethodServiceModel methodService = new MethodServiceModel();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {                          
                        methodService.NameService = reader["NOMBRE"].ToString();
                        methodService.Url = reader["URL_SERVICIO_WEB"].ToString();
                        methodService.HeaderName = reader["NOMBRE_ENCABEZADO"].ToString();
                        methodService.HeaderValue = reader["VALOR"].ToString();
                        methodService.PeriodicityId = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["VALOR_PEROPDICIDAD"]);                      
                        list.Add(methodService);
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                }                   

                tran.Commit();
                conn.Close();

                return list;
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return list;
    }
```

And this is my model class:

```
public class MethodServiceModel
{
    public string NameService { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string HeaderName { get; set; }
    public string HeaderValue { get; set; }
    public decimal PeriodicityId { get; set; }
}
```

I just want that when I consult the two or more rows, the `HeaderName` and the `HeaderValue`, I can differentiate and manipulate each one of them

That's how it looks in my database:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating `MethodServiceModel` outside of the while loop, so each time you are adding an item to the list, you are modifying the same instance each time. When you are adding the object to your list, you are adding a reference, not a copy.

You should move the line `MethodServiceModel methodService = new MethodServiceModel();` inside your while loop.

Comment: Thank you. Was a very important help